# Некорректная кодировка данных в таблице

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Решил написать парсер. В процессе написания решил, что надо данные записывать в таблицу, но, увидев результат, сразу расстроился: как я понимаю, проблема с кодировкой, но не очень понимаю, как ее решить:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

CSV = 'cards.csv'
HOST = 'https://ural-toys.ru/'
URL = 'https://ural-toys.ru/catalog/all/'
HEADERS = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36',
}

def get_html(x):
    r = requests.get('https://ural-toys.ru/catalog/all/' + str(x) + str('-50/1-0/0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0/'))
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'b-catalog__item')
    cards = []

    for item in items:
        cards.append(
            {
                'title' : item.find('div', class_='b-catalog__item-title-wrap').get_text(strip = True).encode(encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore').decode('utf-8', 'ignore'),
                'link_product': HOST + item.find('div', class_='b-catalog__item-title-wrap').find('a').get('href'),
                'img': HOST + item.find('div', class_='b-catalog__item-wrap').find('a').get('href'),
                'price' : item.find('div', class_='b-catalog__item-price').get_text(strip = True)
            }
        )
    return cards

def save_doc(items, path):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter = ';')
        writer.writerow(['Название продукта', 'Ссылка на продукт', 'Картинка', 'Цена'])
        for item in items:
            writer.writerow([item['title'],item['link_product'],item['img'],item['price']])

def parser():
    PAGENATION = input('Укажите количество страниц для парсинга: ')
    PAGENATION = int(PAGENATION.strip())
    html = get_html(1)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        cards = []
        stringTwo = '-100'
        for page in range(1, PAGENATION):
            print(f'Парсинг еще в процессе, страница: {page}')
            html = get_html(page)
            #pages.append(requests.get('https://ural-toys.ru/catalog/all/' + str(x) + str('-50/1-0/0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0/')))
            cards.extend(get_content(html.text))
            save_doc(cards, CSV)
        print(cards)
    else:
        print('Error')

parser()

# max_page = 2
# pages = []
#
# for x in range(1, max_page + 1):
#     pages.append( requests.get('https://ural-toys.ru/catalog/all/' + str(x) + str('-50/1-0/0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0/'  ) ) )
#
# for r in pages:
#     html = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
#
#     for el in html.select('.b-catalog__item'):
#         title = el.select('.b-price__num')
#         print( title[0].text
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Никогда, тоесть вообще никогда, не работайте с csv в excel. Если для Вас целостность данных имеет значение, единственный вариант затащить их туда из csv через power query

Comment: а других вариантов, как я понимаю, нет?

Comment: Есть, просто это первое что пришло в голову, от души так сказать )))

Comment: def save_doc(items, path):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='', encoding="cp1251") as file:

Comment: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0306' in position 12: character maps to <undefined>
такую ошибку выдает
а когда ставлю utf-8, то выдает артефакты

Comment: странно, у меня ваш код корректно отработал с этим исправлением

Comment: там 767 страниц надо спарсить, на 37 выдается ошибка

Comment: Сделайте обработку этой ошибки

Comment: я немного неопытен, можно поподробнее про обработку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение нашел:

```
with open(path, 'w+', newline='', encoding="cp1251", errors='replace') as file:
```